# I got an error while Gradle sync process "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'."

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio, the exactly error is

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward, you need to wither update the google-services plugin or the com.google.android.gms dependency version. On your build.gradle files you should find the lines corresponding to these dependencies and update them accordingly.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In order for us to answer your question more precisely, could you paste the content of your build.gradle scripts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a specific gms service only  other wise if you make com.google.android.gms:11.8.0' it will load all gms services so if you need ads make it ad like below Go to build gradle(module app) and make
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'